# Include navigation prop on ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this `Keuring` class and I have a problem including a navigation item on the `Testresultaten` collection property  using linq.

```
public partial class Keuring
{
    public Keuring()
    {
        Testresultaten = new HashSet<Testresultaten>();
    }

    //Simple properties here

    //Complex properties below
    public virtual ICollection<Testresultaten> Testresultaten { get; set; }
    public virtual Gereedschap Gereedschap { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the `Testresultaten` class:

```
public partial class Testresultaten
{
    //Simple properties here

    //Complex properties below
    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
    public virtual Keuring Keuring { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the `Gereedschap` class:

```
public partial class Gereedschap
{
    public Gereedschap()
    {
        Keuring = new HashSet<Keuring>();
    }

    //Simple properties here

    //Complex properties below
    public virtual ICollection<Keuring> Keuring { get; set; }
    public virtual Debiteur Debiteur { get; set; }
}
```

This statement works fine:

```
var keuringEntry = db.Keuring.Include(item => item.Gereedschap).Include(item => item.Testresultaten).SingleOrDefault(item => item.key = "keyvalue");
```

But when I add an extra `Include` like this:
`Include(item => item.Testresultaten.Select(subItem => subItem.Test))`
the statement gives an error:

```
var keuringEntry = db.Keuring.Include(item => item.Gereedschap).Include(item => item.Testresultaten.Select(subItem => subItem.Test)).SingleOrDefault(item => item.key = "keyvalue");
```

Error:
The property expression 'x => {from Testresultaten subItem in [x].Testresultaten select [subItem].Test}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

The `Test` var in the `Testresultaten` class is a property and not a field. What am I doing wrong? And it is accesable just like `Gereedschap` is in `Keuring`

Comment: And Test is an entity in your model?

Comment: Take a look at [`ThenInclude`](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#id2)

Comment: Yes it is an entity

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it as shown below.

```
var keuringEntry = db.Keuring.Include(item => item.Gereedschap)
                  .Include(item => item.Testresultaten)
                       .ThenInclude(subItem => subItem.Test)
                  .FirstOrDefault(item => item.key = "keyvalue");
```

**Refernce :** [**Including multiple levels**](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#including-multiple-levels)